# Anorm multi-value support doesn't work

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, anorm

I have this weird issue with Anorm's multi-value support, my query doesn't return anything when I use `Seq` as written in [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAnorm).. Here is my query:

**Controller**

```
def checkStock(data: Recap): Boolean =  DB.withConnection { implicit conn =>
    var so_id_list: Set[String] = Set()
    for(ls <- data.recap_items){
        for(rs <- ls.invoice_items){
            so_id_list = so_id_list ++ Set(rs.id.toString)
        }
    }
    breakable{
        play.api.Logger.info(so_id_list.toSeq.toString)
        //return ArrayBuffer(4, 5)
        val result = Sales_Order.getSO_detailbyIDlist(so_id_list.toSeq)
        play.api.Logger.info(result.toString)
        //return List()
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
def getSO_detailbyIDlist(so_id_list: Seq[String]):List[SO_detail] = DB.withConnection{ implicit c =>
    SQL("""SELECT detailso.sur_key, detailso.so_id AS so_id, detailso.product_id, detailso.qty, product.name, detailso.unit_name, detailso.unit_multiplier, detailso.price, detailso.discount, detailso.contract, COALESCE(rs.left_qty, 0) AS left_qty
        FROM detailso
        LEFT JOIN product ON detailso.product_id = product.id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT Product.id, COALESCE(SUM(StockCard.left_qty), 0) as left_qty
                  FROM Warehouse_Product
                  LEFT JOIN Product ON Product.id = Warehouse_Product.product_id
                  LEFT JOIN Warehouse ON Warehouse.id = Warehouse_Product.warehouse_id
                  LEFT JOIN StockCard ON Stockcard.warehouse_product_id = Warehouse_Product.id
                  WHERE Warehouse.id = '110' AND StockCard.status = 1
                  GROUP BY id) rs ON rs.id = product.id
        WHERE detailso.so_id IN ({so_id_list})
        GROUP BY detailso.sur_key""").on('so_id_list -> so_id_list).as(SO_detailParser *)
}
```

If I change the `IN` query into manual `IN (4,5)`, then it returns as expected. Any idea why my multi-value doesn't work ??

Comment: You need to precise the Anorm version: multi value was released at 2.3.

Comment: You are right, I use Play 2.2.. Thanks.. Do you know any workaround to achieve the same thing ?

Comment: Anorm is available as standalone dependency. Nothing prevent to use 2.3 (even with play2.2).

Comment: So, then how can I upgrade my Anorm ? Currently in my sbt it's only `anorm` without a version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade Anorm to 2.3 having this feature by removing from your SBT project the depencency constant `anorm` provided by Play, and adding a fully qualified/standalone dependency.

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.3.7")
//2.3.7 is just an example, you can change it to any other version
```

Comment: Quick question here, after changing to 2.3.7. I got an error `No implicit view available from Any => anorm.ParameterValue.` when inserting the last ID that's returned by `executeInsert()`. Any idea ?

Comment: Not a quick question, it deserves its own question for details. See Anorm section at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23 (your parameter type need to be explicit/with no erasure, for safe SQL conversion).